# Google Notifier and nested labels

Tags: gmail, applescript

My company switched from Exchange to GMail and since I already had a GMail account I decided to forward all the company email to my personal one. To keep things organized and to satisfy my OCD I have a ton of filters and labels. Google Notifier is annoying as it will only alert you to new items in one label. You can hack that to some extent (on a Mac) by typing this into Terminal: defaults write com.google.GmailNotifier Label -string "LABEL NAME HERE", be it the Inbox or one of your own.

So, in a flash of brilliance I hacked together an AppleScript that reads all my top level labels from a text file stored in my Documents folder, loops through them, runs a shell script to change which label Google Notifier is checking and then, with a little Growl hackery and their plug-in displays them as a Growl notification. Sweet! Set a delay for moving between labels and an idle call and let it run all day. (Actually I don't do an idle call, I check the time and do a while the time doesn't equal x loop).

OK, so on to my question. Refer back to the OCD comment. I have a lot of labels that are parent->child relationships, for example Sports has sub labels of Karate, Lacrosse, WestMont and KidsSports. Lacrosse itself has several sub levels for the various teams my kids play on.  I can access Sports through this code: com.google.GmailNotifier Label -string "Sports" but if I put in com.google.GmailNotifier Label -string "Sports/Lacrosse" no dice. If I put in just Lacrosse it doesn't find it either. So does anyone know the correct path to get to child labels?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever manage to get this working?

Comment: Unfortunately no, and then I tabled the project and haven't looked at it in a while.

Comment: Quite an old question, but still relevant. Anyone managed to get this working?